# sorting map of the key to values with integer and strings

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, iterator, mapping

I am trying to return the mapping of faces to letters for this die. The faces are identified using the Integer values 1 through 6, and the returned map is sorted on its keys (the face numbers). 
My code is as following:

public SortedMap getValueMap() {

```
    SortedMap<Integer, String> sm = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

    sm.put(new Integer(1), "A");
    sm.put(new Integer(2), "A");
    sm.put(new Integer(4), "E");
    sm.put(new Integer(3), "E");
    sm.put(new Integer(5), "G");
    sm.put(new Integer(6), "N");
    Set<Entry<Integer, String>> s = sm.entrySet();

    Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> i = s.iterator();

    for (i=1; i.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) i.next();
        int key = (Integer) m.getKey();
        String sValue = (String) m.getValue();

    }
    return "Key :" + key + "  value :" + sValue;

}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: as per you can see what I am trying to do. However, there are some errors in the code, I do not get it what they are. That is why I posted the question here.

Comment: if you paste the errors, others will be able to help you

Comment: The compiler has told you where it has detected the errors.  **What** do you not understand about what it has told you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize `i=1` here. Change it to a while loop

```
while(i.hasNext())
```